# Angular: Can't bind to 'ngModelOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: angular, validation, angular-material

I've problem with validation. I want to add validation to my email input, but I get error "Can't bind to 'ngModelOptions' since it isn't a known property of 'input'".

### add-component.html

```
<form name="form" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="form.valid" class="form">
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput
           placeholder="Adres e-mail"
           formControlName="email"
           [(ngModel)]="employee.email"
           [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
           [ngClass]="{'is-invalid':form.get('email').touched && form.get('email').invalid}"
           type="email"
           required>
           <div *ngIf="form.get('email').touched && form.get('email').invalid"  class="invalid-feedback">
              <div *ngIf="form.get('email').errors.required">Email Name is required</div>
              <div *ngIf="form.get('email').errors.email">Email must be a valid email Address</div>
           </div>
  </mat-form-field>
```

### add-component.ts

```
form = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.email
    ])
  });
```

I have included FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule in app.module.ts.

Comment: https://next.angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ngModelOptions` directive has changed in [Angular](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#ngmodel) since [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions). Many of the funcionality removed in angular. From angular docs:

> Tracks the configuration options for this ngModel instance.
>
> **name**: An alternative to setting the name attribute on the form control element. See the example for using NgModel as a standalone control.
>
> **standalone**: When set to true, the ngModel will not register itself with its parent form, and acts as if it's not in the form. Defaults to false.
>
> **updateOn**: Defines the event upon which the form control value and validity update. Defaults to 'change'. Possible values: 'change' | 'blur' | 'submit'.

Angular way for validations is to use FormControl:

```
emailFormControl = new FormControl('', [
  Validators.required,
  Validators.email,
]);
```

You can see in this [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/angular/lnerabnmmqx)

Edited, Thanks to @ConnorsFan's comment.

Comment: Please note that `ngModelOptions` is also an input property of the `ngModel` directive (see [the documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#ngmodel)).